# Why is my “Envelope Weights” bone moving way too much?

Tags: rigging, armature

I have a simple skeleton on my character and when I make it the character’s parent using “Envelope Weights”, by default, each bone controls WAY too much! Is this a setting I need to adjust, or is it something I’ve done wrong?
Please bear with me, I’m not very good at rigging.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, is there a reason why you chose Envelope Weights instead of Automatic Weights?

Comment: Automatic weights didn’t do anything.

Comment: You use either weights or envelopes, not both. Either way any automatic weights or default bone envelope is barely a starting point, it's unlikely to perfectly work without you adapting it.

Comment: Automatic Weights should work, I don't think that Envelope fits your need, but maybe share your file